# How can I do this as 1 database query?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a query that looks in the USER table to find the top 9 affiliates based on the frequency of their affiliate code.

```
affs = User.group(:affiliate).limit(9).count.sort_by{|i,j|-j}
(0.6ms)  SELECT  COUNT(*) AS count_all, affiliate AS affiliate FROM "users"  GROUP BY affiliate LIMIT 9
 #=> [["ACE5", 5], ["2YY", 3], ["MB7", 2], ["GB2", 2], ["GHCYM", 1], ["L6EOC", 1], ["15F2", 1], ["R0TK", 1], ["DSB", 1]]
```

Now I take this result and I enumerate over it to get the row corresponding to the user.

```
affs.map do |aff|
  user = User.find_by(qcode: aff.first)
  [user.avatar.url(:thumb), user.name.match(/\w*/)[0], aff.first, aff.last]
end

 #LOG OUTPUT
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."qcode" = 'ACE5' LIMIT 1
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."qcode" = '2YY' LIMIT 1
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."qcode" = 'GB2' LIMIT 1
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."qcode" = 'MB7' LIMIT 1
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."qcode" = 'L6EOC' LIMIT 1
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."qcode" = '15F2' LIMIT 1
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."qcode" = 'R0TK' LIMIT 1
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."qcode" = 'DSB' LIMIT 1
```

**Running this query 9 times seems very redundant. How can I optimize this into 1 or 2 database queries?**

Example USERS table DB Schema:

```
id | email              | name         | qcode  | affiliate
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
25 | kjones@aol.com     | Ken Lu       | DSB    | L6EOC         
26 | broks2@aol.com     | Brains Bruk  | AJ8U   | DSB           
27 | joanshu@aol.com    | Joan Hu      | K9UE   | DSB
```

From the above example. "Ken Lu" is affiliate `DSB` and he is responsible for signing up ID 26 and ID 27. So the above `aff` query would produce:

```
 #=> [["DSB", 2], ...]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the `user` table information for all 9 affiliates at once, you can drop down into raw SQL.

From what I can infer of your schema from the code above, something like this should work (you may need to tweak it a bit if your schema differs from what I inferred; not tested since I don't have your data nor a *Rails* setup handy):

```
WITH top_affiliates AS
(
    SELECT  COUNT(*) AS count_all, affiliate AS affiliate
    FROM users
    GROUP BY affiliate
    ORDER BY count_all
    LIMIT 9
)
SELECT *
FROM top_affiliates AS t
JOIN users AS u ON (t.affiliate = u.qcode)
ORDER BY count_all
```

Note that the `JOIN` assumes that `t.affiliate = u.qcode` will provide a unique mapping between the tables (based on the resulting SQL from when you were iterating over the map, this seemed like a fair assumption). If it's not unique, though, you would need to add additional parameters in the `JOIN` such that the mapping is unique, else you would get additional rows in the result that you wouldn't want.

If you're using *ActiveRecord*, you can use `connection.execute` on the *model* containing this information, and pass the above SQL in as a string (or assign it to a variable first and pass that in).

**Edit in response to comment from OP:**

@f1f5: The `WITH` query defines what's called a *CTE*, which is essentially a temp table scoped to the query itself as opposed to the connection. I can then use that *CTE* in queries underneath the `WITH`, which is what I'm doing above. Basically, the `WITH` query is taking the place of your `User.group(:affiliate).limit(9).count.sort_by{|i,j|-j}` code and then using the results inline to pull the relevant `user` records.

**Edit in response to schema info from OP:**

So, yes, I think my code above will do what you want. Here's an [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/0379d/1/1) I created with the schema data, query, and result.

Comment: Maybe a lack of Postgres knowledge on my part, but it looks like you would need an order clause inside the common table expression to make sure you get the right 9 records out, or put the limit on the outside query.

Comment: If I'm understanding your example correct I think you inferred that top_affiliates is it's own table. It's not. It's all in the USERS table. Basically each USER has an affiliate. I count up all the affiliates. Sort from top 9. Then lookup the qcode on USERS. The qcode is the owner of the affiliate code. Make sense?

Comment: @Laurence: Yes, good catch, thanks. I had it in the second query but forgot to put it in the CTE. I've added it to my answer.

Comment: @Ken your answer update just cleared that up for me. Thanks.. Didn't know you could make a "temp" table... Awesome!!

Comment: Sure, no problem. I added an sqlfiddle link to my answer. Based on your schema example plus that, I'm pretty sure my code above will do what you want.

Comment: Ken I just tested it and yep it works as expected and blazing fast... Awesome!! Thank you so much.. Can you recommend some reading specifically on SQL that can get me up to speed maybe like a "tricks guide" or a "cheat sheet" ?? Thanks again!

Comment: Sure, no problem. [This link](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Slow_Query_Questions) has some things to try at the bottom for slow queries. [SQL Cookbook](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596009762.do) has some good techniques/"recipes" which still hold up, although due to its age (it's over 8 years old), it doesn't reflect things like *Postgres* now supports *Window* functions.